# Problem with VSCode remote Powershell - Could not detect Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have installed Python 3.10 with PATH setting enabled and it got installed, and is also detected by running the following command in CMD and Powershell:

> python --version

But the problem is that when I connect to this computer over VSCode SSH and run the same command on Powershell, it says that I need to download Python from the Microsoft Store. Although when I run code on VSCode remote SSH via the "play button", it does execute. Just not on the integrated terminal.

Problem worsens if I install Python3.10 as per the request the VSCode Powershell asks me to. In that case, 2 different versions of Python3.10 run in parallel, which creates confusion as the MS-Store installed Python runs on VSCode Powershell, and the original one on "Play button execution". The problem with this newer (store-based) Python install is that it can't detect my GPU and other CUDA libraries no matter what I do. I even uninstalled the original Python installation but got no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs on [ssh](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) and [Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

[image]

What you need to install is the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension.

> I found was only for that session, and the other command which was for permanent, did not work in VSCode powershell.

Temporary variables do not work, and administrator permissions are required to set permanent variables. You can add environment variables in the advanced system settings to permanently apply.

[image]

Comment: Already did this. Still got no luck. When I run using the execute button, it runs fine, and the output terminal shows full path to python (like & "C:\Users...\python.exe" filename.py). If I do this manually, it works without a problem. However, when in the same vscode powershell if I directly try "python" command, it cannot find python (it needs full path). In the host computer, it doesn't (runs directly using "python" command"). All system and local environment vars are upto date but nothing happens. In VSCode, if I want to use command directly, I have to create environment variable at run.

Comment: You said in the question that you confirmed the installation of Python through command `python-version`, but the comment said that the Python command did not work. What is the real problem?

Comment: Just to clear, python --version is working in the host's powershell. In the VSCode powershell, I have to specify the entire path to python and do the --version for it to work. I researched around and found that we can set environment var in powershell, but the command I found was only for that session, and the other command which was for permanent, did not work in VSCode powershell. So to summarize: I installed Python 3.10 on the host WITH the env variables for both system and user, which is working well for local sessions, but NOT for vscode remote sessions. All relevant vscode exts installed

Comment: Temporary variables do not work, and administrator permissions are required to set permanent variables

Comment: Tried. It worked! Thanks! I wonder why I had to add it with powershell, when it was already present in system environment variables. But adding the same did the job. It seems that the environment variables don't work in SSH environment unless added manually via powershell.